# PostgreSQL statement to change a static field in rows to be numbered sequentially

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data represented as follows:

```
App_id    Type
123       Dependent
987       Dependent
456       Dependent
```

I want to write a CASE statement in PostgreSQL so that it will be reflected as the following:

```
App_id    Type
123       1
987       2
456       3
```

*There are multiple other columns in the table but this specific data needs to be represented as a cumulative count (when the type = dependent).

I'm not sure how to go about this when the value is the same (e.g. Dependent) and reflected more than once.

Comment: You need to define the row order somehow.

Comment: What does that mean and how do I go about that?

Comment: For example, how do you decide which App_id should have Type = 2? Remember that tables are unordered by default.

Comment: That's the thing - i just want it to count cumulatively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` by this way you will get unique row number for Type :

```
select t.app_id, t.type, 
       row_number() over (partition by t.type order by t.app_id) as rowno_type
from table t;
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!